# import win32service, win32api, win32con, winerror ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a Microsoft Service, but this error appears, the complete name error:

> "File "PythonCornerExample.py", line 1, in 
>       import win32serviceutil
>     File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\win32\lib\win32serviceutil.py", line 9, in 
>       import win32service, win32api, win32con, winerror
>
> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.".

I've already tried  to install Visual C++ redistributable 2015, but the error still exist.

This is the code:

````
import win32service
import win32event
import servicemanager
import socket


class AppServerSvc (win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = "TestService"
    _svc_display_name_ = "Test Service"

    def __init__(self,args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self,args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None,0,0,None)
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(60)

    def SvcStop(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
                              servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED,
                              (self._svc_name_,''))
        self.main()

    def main(self):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(AppServerSvc)```
````

Comment: It looks like you have installed the 32-bit version of Python for Windows but you are trying to run it from a 64-bit Python interpreter or vice versa. Windows executables can't load DLLs of a different bitness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to reinstall python in 64bit

link:
https://www.python.org